# How to construct a JUnit testing for a method that uses some random in it

Tags: java, eclipse, random, junit, random-seed

I have a method that uses a set of numbers that is randomly picked (for example, choosing 10 random number from a `1-100`).

I need to "use a seed" in order to create a "deterministic" set - which will allow me to preform JUnit tests for the method itself and the object it creates as a result...

How do we use such a seed?
(I do not want to use hard coding of the set in the function and creating a "test" flag for the method).